# Filter a nested list in a object and return a object of same type

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
class Restaurant{
  List<Menu> menus;
}

class Menu {
  List <SubMenu> subMenus;
}

class SubMenu {
  AvailableService availableService;
}

AvailableService {
  bool collection;
  bool delivery;
  bool table;
}

Restaurant restaurant = Restaurant();
```

When data is loaded I have different services for my submenus;

I'm looking for a way to filter my `restaurant` object by `availableService`.
For example a restaurant object with only submenus for delivery.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```dart
Restaurant().menus.where((m) => m.subMenus.where((s) => s.availableService.delivery).isNotEmpty);
```

Comment: thanks, but restaurant is an object. I don't need a list of restaurants ...just the one restaurant. The lists are nested in the object

Comment: thanks, doesn't seem to be compiling and returning a bool

Comment: Sorry, corrected and checked in dartpad.dev.

Comment: it returns an Iterable<Menu>

Comment: Yes. You can check it by `isEmpty` and it is your answer, if collections is empty, restaurant is not equal to criteria.